# App doesn't load an SQLite database on other machines

Tags: qt, sqlite, dynamic-linking

I have an app that uses an SQLite database. I'm trying to get a demo version to work, so I can show it to the person I am making it for, it runs, but it refuses to do any sort of SQL. Importing a database, reading it, or creating a new one - nothing happens. Usually such things happen because one or another library is missing - but I doubt that's the case. `qsqlite.dll` is safe and sound in the `sqldrivers` folder in the root directory, and `Qt5Sql.dll` is in the root directory as well. According to Dependancy Walker I'm not missing any libraries. (also resizing images on `resizeEvent()` doesn't work... huh?!"

What could be the reason here?

```
/imageformats/qjpegd.dll
/platforms/qwindowsd.dll
/sqldrivers/qsqlited.dll
app.exe
icudt54.dll
icuin54.dll
icuuc54.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Cored.dll
Qt5Guid.dll
Qt5Sqld.dll
Qt5Widgetsd.dll
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem after dropping the issue... this time the answer isn't the usual "wrong library". No. Wrong compilation.

I compiled with MinGW, while after compiling with regular Qt Desktop 5.5 it worked.